# Nginx 502 Bad Gateway Error

Tags: centos, php, php-fpm, php7

Currently have a 502 Bad Gateway Error on my Centos 6.8 Server.

```
    2017/01/30 23:57:31 [crit] 26911#0: *1 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.15, server: 192.168.0.$
```

I checked whether the directory existed and it doesn't. The closest I could find to the folder was /var/run/php-fpm, which only contains php-fpm.pid.

Comment: php-fpm needs to actually be running.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps to troubleshoot this issue:

1. Check if `php-fpm` is running:

   ```
   sudo service php-fpm status
   sudo service php7-php-fpm status # use this if you are using remi PHP 7
   ```
2. Check for the `listen` directive in php-fpm’s www.conf configuration file:

   ```
   grep -Ri listen /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf 
   grep -Ri listen /etc/opt/remi/php70/php-fpm.d # for remi
   ```
3. Make sure your nginx `fastcgi_pass` directive matches your `listen` directive.

Answer (score 0):

For me the setup process is this, after installing nginx from the [nginx.org repo](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/#official-red-hat-centos-packages):

```
mkdir -p /var/www/public_html
chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/public_html
restorecon -rv /var/www
yum install php-fpm
sed -i 's@listen = 127.0.0.1:9000@listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock@' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
sed -i 's@;listen.owner = nobody@listen.owner = nobody@' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
sed -i 's@;listen.group = nobody@listen.group = nobody@' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
sed -i 's@user = apache@user = nginx@' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
sed -i 's@group = apache@group = nginx@' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
systemctl start php-fpm.service
systemctl enable php-fpm.service
```

Then your host config should be something like:

```
server
{
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www/public_html;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$
    {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Then restart nginx and there you go.